# Different certificates for the same domain name with letsencrypt

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, haproxy, lets-encrypt

I have a bunch of ec2 nodes (serve HTTP) behind two haproxy nodes (client facing HTTPS). There are two A entries for my domain name, so clients send requests to both haproxy nodes. Each new request goes to a different IP than the previous one.

With dns-01 challenge, I can obtain SSL certificate for my domain on both haproxy nodes. As a result, there will be two independent SSL certificates on two servers, both for the same domain.

Is it generally a good idea? Are there any major downsides? Is it better to obtain one certificate and copy it between the haproxy nodes?

Comment: You might run into issues with certificate pinning. I'd think it's *generally* fine to do, though.

Comment: While that's probably true, having just one certificate that's duplicated on all of the nodes would avoid any problem, and I don't see any reason not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to using ELB+Haproxy+Backends, with ELB doing ssl stripping and use free certs from AWS Certificate Manager. Should be really easy to switch, with next to no performance impact, but with some cost impact.

In general, having multiple certificates for EXACTLY the same domain is not harmful, unless it's EV or DV cert, but as you are using let's encrypt, that's not an issue. It's only a pain to take care of.